# Bootstrap NavBar: Is there a way to disable a few menu items even the parent for certain pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Is there a way to disable certain menu items and or its parent for certain pages, but i'm using a single navbar.jsp for all pages and its being loaded by a javascript on every page.

**NavBar.jsp**

```
<body>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a href="home.html" class="navbar-brand">SYSTRIX</a>
            </div>

                <div class="navbar-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">My Console<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="home.html">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="users.html">User Management</a></li>
                                <li><a href="patients.html">Patient Management</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">New<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="userProfile.html">User</a></li>
                                <li><a href="patientsProfile.html">Patient</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Admission</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>   

                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Edit<b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">User Roles</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Patient Episode</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Patient Staff Assignment</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>

                        <li><a href="#">Help</a></li>

                        <form class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="search">
                            <div class="form-group">
                                <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Search">
                            </div>
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success">Submit</button>
                        </form>                     
                    </ul>
                </div>
        </div>
    </nav>
</body>
```

**Script:**

```
<script> 
$(function(){
  $("#includedContent").load("navbar.jsp"); 
});
</script>
```

I need to disable certain menu items for certain .jsp pages Like the edit should not be available if i'm on the add new page. Thank you for your help.

Comment: There are many ways to do it, like using classes

Comment: you can add a function , so after the loading is complete, it'll trigger that function.And in that function , you can work with conditions to remove or add classes... Give us some pages with what menu items you want to disable or anything you want, and we'll show you how to do it...

Comment: @Ayadi I really appreciate it. Roles.jsp, PatientEpisode.jsp, & StaffAssignment.jsp  will have the parent Edit menu. And when Each of this page is loaded, Roles.jsp will have an active User Roles menu item active, PatientEpisode.jsp will have Patient Episode menu active , and StaffAssignment.jsp will have the Patient Staff Assignment menu item available. Thank you very much for your time. :D

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will work for you:

You should change your part of code to this :

```
<li class="dropdown">
    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Edit<b class="caret"></b></a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li><a href="#" id="userroles">User Roles</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="patientepisode">Patient Episode</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" id="patientstaff">Patient Staff Assignment</a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

And use this jquery code :

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var url = window.location.pathname;
var filename = url.substring(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

if(filename == 'Roles.jsp'){
    $('#patientepisode').addClass('disabled');
    $('#patientstaff').addClass('disabled');
}else if(filename == 'PatientEpisode.jsp'){
    $('#userroles').addClass('disabled');
    $('#patientstaff').addClass('disabled');
}else if(filename == 'StaffAssignment.jsp'){
    $('#userroles').addClass('disabled');
    $('#patientepisode').addClass('disabled');
}
});
```

I hope this'll help you.

Comment: Thank you. I just had to use .parent().addClass('disabled'); and it worked. Thanks a lot. :)